# display a 2 row message pop -up vba 6

Tags: string, excel, vba, msgbox

is there a way to display a 2 or 3 or 4 or n line message on a pop-up window in vba 6 ?

For the moment my pop-up window ( calling the MsgBox function) displays the message like this :

```
       You did something wrong. Please enter valid input.
```

and I want it to display the message like this

```
      You did something wrong. 
     Please enter valid input.
```

can you please provide a code sample?

many thx in advance,
radu

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add a newline in your message:

```
MsgBox "Text 1" & vbNewLine & "text 2.
```

Comment: can you please direct me to more of the vba vbConstants?

Comment: @Radu: Not sure where to get an exhaustive list, but this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211774) has a small list. Otherwise just type vb and then press `Ctrl + Space` and the autocomplete will give you a list.

Comment: good tip.  I'll have to keep that one in mind.  Learn something new every day.

Comment: thanks a lot for the article, and for the intelisense suggestion. that and F1 will give me a place to start. many many thx!!!

Answer (score 4):

Relatively easy request

```
    iResult = MsgBox("This information is on the first line. " & vbCrLf & "This information is on the 2nd line. " &vbCrLf & _
        "Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Message Box")
```

Comment: hey, thank you very much!!!, haven't got the chance to test it, but 11 gold medals say a lot more than I can say :)